# Windows, OpenSSL generate a new .pem from key.pem and cert.pem

Tags: windows, openssl, pem

I have the following files Cert.pem, Key.pem, CACert.pem

I have been told that I need to decrypt the key.pem.
1) What is the windows OpenSSL command to do this?

I need to combine the decrypted key.pem file with the cert.pem file to produce a new cert.pem file.
2) What is the windows OpenSSL command to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It is about programming and development. I need to generate a key for my Java keystore. Security is an important part of development.

Answer (score 0):

Unix installations of OpenSSL should include man pages, but Windows versions often do not because Windows doesn't usually have any way of finding and displaying them. man pages for the *currently supported* releases, plus 'master' which is the development head, are available on the OpenSSL website at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manpages.html . All OpenSSL 'commands' are actually run by the (single) program `openssl`, thus you execute `pkey some args` by running

```
 openssl pkey some args
 rem if openssl.exe is on your PATH or in the current directory, otherwise
 x:\path\to\openssl pkey some args
```

You don't mention having the password for the encrypted key file; I hope you do because you can't decrypt (or do anything else) without it.

For 1.0.0 up, `pkey` is the preferred way to convert private keys, including encrypting and decrypting; see its man page. In brief you simply tell `pkey` to read from the input file and write to the output file, and *omit* any specification of a cipher; that omission will cause it to write an unencrypted key. Note `pkey` will write the output in PKCS8 format, which is preferred for most purposes, but if you actually need a 'legacy' or 'traditional' format for some reason -- ask whoever 'told' you what software this file will be used with -- 1.1.0 `pkey` can do this but earlier cannot.
If you are stuck with a 0.9.x release, usually only on obsolete systems, use `pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt` for PCKS8 output; see that.

If you need legacy/traditional format (on a release below 1.1.0) you must use the 'legacy' per-algorithm commands, so you need to know what algorithm your key(file) *is*. Look at the first line where it says `-----BEGIN something PRIVATE KEY-----` . If something is RSA, use `rsa`; for DSA `dsa`; for EC `ec`; see the respective pages. If something is `ENCRYPTED` you must decrypt it to PkCS8 as above first, then look at it with `asn1parse` to determine which algorithm it is, but I expect it's not very likely someone who want a legacy unencrypted key will start with an PKCS8 encrypted one.

OpenSSL does not provide any special operation to combine PEM files, since concatenating files of many types is a common operation. On Unix this is canonically done with the `cat` program; on Windows it can be done by using the (builtin) `copy` command with plus-sign(s) in the source; on both Unix and Windows it can be done by creating a file and then appending to it like:

```
 copy decryptedkey.pem combined.pem
 type certificate.pem >> combined.pem
 rem >> means redirect the output from that command ('type') 
 rem normally on the console to _the end of_ the named file.
```

In this case you want to modify cert.pem by adding the contents of decryptedkey.pem, so just do

```
 type decryptedkey.pem >> cert.pem
```

Alternatively you can use a plaintext editor like notepad. Open both files; select all the text in the second file and copy (or cut) and paste it at the end of the first file; save the modified first file.

Comment: So I have openssl installed on Windows, and there is no pkey command. So at the moment I have a key.pem (encrypted) that I cannot decrypt. How else do I decrypt it without pkey.

Comment: (corrected) @JamesRelic: if you want pkcs8 and you're on 0.9.x, as I wrote, use: `pkcs8 -topk8` **with -nocrypt`** (here it is not default).